# ¿Cómo obtener la ruta relativa de un archivo a partir de una clase C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, rutas

Estoy realizando unas pruebas en **C#** y **Crystal Reports**, pero me he topado con el manejo de archivos.

Mi proyecto se compone de lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando en el formulario `Form1.cs` y la idea es obtener la ruta del archivo `Reporte_Peliculas.rpt` y asignarlo al `reportDocument.Load(...)`, he visto algunos tutoriales donde usan la ruta absoluta, pero es allí donde empieza mi problema, ya que por seguridad no quisiera poner toda la ruta, sino mas bien obtenerla desde la clase que estoy trabajando.

**Ejemplo** `proyecto\Reporte_Peliculas.rpt` (Se que no es asi, pero quise dar la idea de lo que busco)

Comment: En el siguiente link encontraras lo que estas buscando, no necesitas ruta para generar el informe http://programandoconcsharpdotnet.blogspot.com/2012/05/como-crear-un-reporte-de-crystal-en-c.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas Ferny,

Para hacer lo que pides puedes usar la propiedad `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, la cual te devuelve el Path del directorio contenedor del ejecutable que estás ejecutando.

```
reportDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,"Reporte_Peliculas.rpt"));
```

Debes tener en cuenta que `Environment.CurrentDirectory` si estás desarrollando, te va a devolver siempre la ruta terminada con `\bin\Debug` o `\bin\Release` dependiendo de cómo estés compilando, y que seguramente no tengas el reporte en ninguna de esas 2 carpetas, ya que normalmente lo guarda en la carpeta raíz del proyecto, para ello puedes usar sólo cuando estés desarrollando la signueite instrucción:

```
reportDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName,"Reporte_Peliculas.rpt"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Quizá a alguien le sirva, encontré esta [respuesta](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/C-sharp/608535-Rutas-relativas-en-c.html) que me ayudó ya que con la respuesta de @Marc no se por qué me repetía una carpeta.
Lo que usé fue `..\` cada vez que necesitaba subir una carpeta.

`string path = Path.GetFullPath("..\\..\\Reporte\\ReporteServicioTecnico.rpt");`